# Django Fetch column from foreign key table

Tags: python, django

I am new on Django. I have trouble fetching column from the foreign key table.

The task at hand is to create a CSV with some columns from two tables(table 1, table 2). I have created two models as :

```
class SomeDetails(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table2'


class Report(models.Model):
    transfer_platform = models.CharField(verbose_name="Transfer platform", max_length=255)
    status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Status(4=success, 5=failed)")
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    some_uuid = models.ForeignKey('SomeDetails', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table1'
```

csv code:

```
qs = Report.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.today().date() + timedelta(-1)).filter(
                status=4).values('id', 'transfer_platform', 'status', 'amount', 'created_at', 'some_uuid__type')
```

The above doesnt return any data apart from the column headers. But if i remove the 'some_uuid__type' from above query it returns the correct data.

I have also tried prefetch_related, but somehow haven't been able to work it out.

```
qs = Report.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.today().date() + timedelta(-1)).filter(
                status=4).prefetch_related('SomeDetails').values('id', 'transfer_platform', 'status', 'amount', 'created_at', 'some_uuid__type')
```

The above doesn't return anything either.Please help me get all the five columns so that i can populate it in the CSV.

Python version : 2.7

Comment: I don't see where you used `beneficiary_uuid__type` and where you removed it.

Comment: @aquaman I've updated the description